# How to specify the date in a yahoo finance api query?

Tags: yahoo-finance

I'm following the instruction at http://wern-ancheta.com/blog/2015/04/05/getting-started-with-the-yahoo-finance-api/

I'd like to query information for a specific date and I'm not sure how to specify the date. As an example, I used `http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GE+PTR+MSFT&f=snd1l1yr?d2=2016-07-27` but that didn't succeed.

My questions is *how to specify the date to the parameter `d2` in the given API```, not how to get the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting stock's historical data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097779/getting-stocks-historical-data)